# Apache HTTPS / non-WWW redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, https, redirect, bitnami

I'm wanting to re-direct all my web traffic to 
https://example.com

So-far I've got everything **except** https:www.example.com re-directing fine

This is what my Virtual Host Config file looks like

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/ [R,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^https://www.example.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/ [R,L]
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
  ........
```

The only site that doesn't redirect is

https://www.example.com

What am I missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas mentioned, you want to use `HTTP_HOST`. Also your info is redundant and even not useful. Also you redirect port 80 to 443, which means `HTTPS` is going to be off (not set) anyway. And to redirect on port 443, you need that redirect in the 443 definition.

```
# http://... to https://...
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
  ...
</VirtualHost>

# https://www.example.com -> https://example.com
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Also you probably want the `$1` so you do not lose the path when redirecting.

As mentioned by Thomas, `\.` is a good idea or you could end up matching more than expected (for a host, it's unlikely, though...)

Comment: Cheers for that! Solved my issue straight away! Everything now redirects to https://example.com
Sweet!

Answer (score 1):

`HTTPS_HOST` doesn't exist as far as I'm aware, you want `HTTP_HOST`. Additionally, the `HTTP_HOST` variable does not include the scheme.

Also, although technically it will still work, you might want to escape your `.`'s (except in `RewriteRule` substitutions) as those have a special meaning in a regular expression context (meaning "any character"). Of course a dot also qualifies as *any* character, it's still good practice.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/ [R,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/ [R,L]
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks very much for the help!